# Angular/Bootstrap - Toggle/collapse table row with specific ID?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, datatables, angular-ui-bootstrap

Working in Angular and Bootstrap at the moment and having some difficulties with tables and collapsing rows.

I import data from a database and output them in a table that I generate with *ngFor and two rows inside a ng-container. I want to have the second row collapsed with a toggle button inside the first row. But, when I use the collapse functionality from bootstrap, all the rows go open when I click the button, not just the row I want to target.
Is there a good way to give a unique ID to the rows, so that Angular knows which row to collapse?

In the code below I created a + button with data-target="#collapseRow" in the first row and in the second row I give it an ID (id="collapseRow")

```
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">{{ 'Sales.Location' | translate }}</th>
        <th scope="col">{{ 'Sales.CreationDate' | translate }}</th>
        <th scope="col">{{ 'Sales.MachineNumber' | translate }}</th>
        <th scope="col">{{ 'Sales.Units' | translate }}</th>
        <th scope="col">{{ 'Sales.Price' | translate }}</th>
        <th scope="col">{{ 'Sales.AmountPaid' | translate }}</th>
        <th scope="col">{{ 'Sales.PaymentMethod' | translate }}</th>
        <th scope="col">{{ 'Sales.Status' | translate }}</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <ng-container *ngFor="let sale of sales">
        <tr>
          <td>{{sale.locationId}}</td>
          <td>{{sale.creationTimestamp | date:'medium'}}</td>
          <td>{{sale.machineNumber}}</td>
          <td>{{sale.units}}</td>
          <td>{{sale.price | currency:'EUR'}}</td>
          <td>{{sale.amountPaid | currency:'EUR' }}</td>
          <td>
            <div 
              *ngIf="sale.accountPayments.length">
              {{'Sales.PaymentMethod.Account' | translate }}
                <span 
                  class="badge badge-primary ml-1"
                  type="button" 
                  data-toggle="collapse" 
                  data-target="#collapseRow" 
                  aria-expanded="false" 
                  aria-controls="collapseRow"
                >+</span>
            </div>
            <div *ngIf="isElectronicPaymentSuccess(sale)">{{'Sales.PaymentMethod.Electronic' | translate }}</div>
            <div *ngIf="isCashPaymentSuccess(sale)">{{'Sales.PaymentMethod.Cash' | translate }}</div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <span
              class="badge"
              [ngClass]="{'badge-success' : sale.saleStatus === 'SUCCESS',
                        'badge-danger' : sale.saleStatus === 'ABORTED'}"
            >{{sale.saleStatus}}
            </span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="bg-light collapse" id="collapseRow">
          <td colspan="10">
            <div><span class="font-weight-bold">{{ 'Sales.AccountPayments.CustomerLocalId' | translate }}:</span>{{sale.accountPayments.customerLocalId}}</div>
            <div><span class="font-weight-bold">{{ 'Sales.BonusAmount' | translate }}:</span>{{sale.creditBonusAmount | currency:'EUR'}}</div>
            <div><span class="font-weight-bold">{{ 'Sales.RechargedBy' | translate }}:</span>{{sale.creditRechargeCustomer?.firstName}} {{sale.creditRechargeCustomer?.lastName}}</div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </ng-container>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: `#collapseRow` has to be unique. Currently all collapsible rows have the same ID. IDs have to be unique in HTML anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your button to:

```
<span 
    class="badge badge-primary ml-1"
    type="button" 
    data-toggle="collapse" 
    data-target="#collapseRow{{sale.id}}" 
    aria-expanded="false" 
    aria-controls="collapseRow"
>+</span>
```

and your row to:

```
<tr class="bg-light collapse" id="collapseRow{{sale.id}}">
    <td colspan="10">
    <div><span class="font-weight-bold">{{ 'Sales.AccountPayments.CustomerLocalId' | translate }}:</span>{{sale.accountPayments.customerLocalId}}</div>
    <div><span class="font-weight-bold">{{ 'Sales.BonusAmount' | translate }}:</span>{{sale.creditBonusAmount | currency:'EUR'}}</div>
    <div><span class="font-weight-bold">{{ 'Sales.RechargedBy' | translate }}:</span>{{sale.creditRechargeCustomer?.firstName}} {{sale.creditRechargeCustomer?.lastName}}</div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

If you don't have an ID, use something else as long as this is unique.